# VBA Excel: Populating string with alternating cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have two rows of cells which I use to create a string. The catch is, I need to create the string alternating the two groups of cells. Example below. The two rows of cells need to appear as as such.

"1 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 0 6 1 7 0 8 1 9"

Basically each cell in Amplitude is preceded by a cell from Sign.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the 2 rows together with ease using one for loop if those are the only requirement from your question:

Hardcoded version (assuming "Data Point" sits at cells A1):

```
for i = 1 to 9
ans = ans & Cells(4, i+3) & Cells(2, i+3)
next
```

Now I will let you try something yourself for non-hardcode

Comment: Perfect did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, but that string doesn't seem very useful and there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're after:

```
Dim rowAmplitude As Long
rowAmplitude = 4 ' CHANGE THIS

Dim rowSign As Long
rowSign = 6 ' CHANGE THIS

Dim colStart As Long
colStart = 4 ' CHANGE THIS

Dim colEnd As Long
colEnd = 10 ' CHANGE THIS

Dim msg As String

Dim c As Long
For c = colStart To colEnd
    If msg <> "" Then msg = msg & " "
    msg = msg & Cells(rowSign, c).Value
    msg = msg & " "
    msg = msg & Cells(rowAmplitude, c).Value
Next
```

An improvement would be to name each of your ranges, let's say you call them `DataAmplitudes` and `DataSigns`.  Then the code would be:

```
Dim numCells As Long
numCells = Range("DataAmplitudes").Cells.Count

Dim msg As String

Dim c As Long
For c = 1 To numCells
    If msg <> "" Then msg = msg & " "
    msg = msg & Range("DataSigns").Cells(c).Value
    msg = msg & " "
    msg = msg & Range("DataAmplitudes").Cells(c).Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Gunna be honest though...yours seems a little over engineered...I was able to solve it using a variation of Alex's code. `For i = 4 To N + 3
        hexVal = hexVal & Cells(4, i) & " " & Cells(3, i)
       Next i`

Comment: What happens if you add rows to your sheet?  That's when named ranges and stating everything explicity comes in handy.

Comment: You raise a good point but in this case I won't be adding rows. Thanks though! Also Theoretically, using the method I used, I can keep adding rows no problem because I can just place each `Cells(x, i)` in the order I need it to be written.

Comment: Hard-coding row and column numbers in macros is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this, nothing fancy

```
Sub test()
Range("D3").Activate
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-VBA solution:

[image]

You can see cell B5's formula at work.  As you drag it right, the string build based on the results to the left.

Cell A5 is:

```
=A3 & " " & A1 & " "
```

Cell B5 is:

```
=A5 & B3 & " " & B1 & " "
```

Of course I've added spaces in between digits here, but that's not necessary, it just appeared to be the way your question is formatted.  I don't see any of the answers above providing that, so if you wish to omit the spaces, just eliminate all [& " "] combinations.

Like:

```
=A5 & B3 & B1
```